# XmlDocument.Save changes text containing '\t' to tab

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have this issue wherein whenever I save the xml attribute value which contains '\t' (example: MyNetwork\trash), I get "MyNetwork     rash". Also, there are some wherein the '\n' in the text get changed to a hexadecimal value.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
Config mmsConfig = new Config
{
   Path = "MyNetwork\trash"
};

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(configFile);
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("MMS");

foreach (XmlNode node in 
         from XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes 
         from XmlNode node in xmlNode.ChildNodes 
         select node)
{
   if (node.Attributes == null)
   {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(configFile, "Unable to locate attributes");
   }

   if (node.Attributes["path"] != null)
   {
      node.Attributes["path"].Value = @config.Path;
   }
}

XmlTextWriter xmlText = new XmlTextWriter(configFile, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlText.Formatting = Formatting.None;

xml.Save(xmlText);
xmlText.Close();
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Path = @"MyNetwork\trash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `\`, otherwise `\t` will be interpreted as a special character,

```
Config mmsConfig = new Config
{
   Path = "MyNetwork\\trash"
                    ^
};
```

Check out the **Instantiating a String object** section in [String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> Note that in C#, because the backslash (`\`) is an escape character,
>   literal backslashes in a string must be escaped or the entire string
>   must be @-quoted.

Comment: So I guess I would need to do string manipulation in order to append another '\' correct?

Comment: @Musikero31, just use \\ if you want to append an \ to your string. Or, use `@` in front of the string you want to append. I've added a link to my response.

Comment: I did an extension method in order to handle this. But this solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that \t in a string creates a tab character (similar to how \n creates a new line, \" creates a speech mark and \\ creates a backwardslash). Remember, whenever you put a \ in a string, it needs to be doubled up. Replace the \t with \\t and it should work.

Alternatively, put an @ before the string e.g. @"MyNetwork\Trash". Note that if an @ appears before the string and you want to put a " in the string, you need to use "" e.g. @"A speechmark looks like this: ""."

Answer (score 0):

\t converts to tab(6 spaces)

\n converts to new line

You can use a @ symbol before to escape these.

```
string p = @"MyNetwork\trash";
```

Comment: I tried that one with this code: `node.Attributes["path"].Value = @config.Path;` but it still does not get the result that I want.

Comment: Are you sure its not a problem with the xpath? Try with hardcoded text in debug mode to be sure you have the xpaths correct

Comment: Nope. I placed the code above so that you can see that I already did that. I've also added `@config.Path` just to ensure it but still having problems.

Comment: The @ symbol should be added for literal strings only as in the answers mentioned. Also, are you able to compile the code?

Answer (score 0):

`\t` and `\n` are [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) so you need to escape their `\` to `\\t`  or `\\n`